# Is there a way to associate chrome profiler with console logs or place markers on timeline?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, profiler

I have a couple of visual glitches in my application, and I'm trying to track them down. When profiling with chrome profiler, I can see the glitches frame by frame. However, the events associated with them in the waterfall view below are non descriptive, and I'd like to be able to hone in on what's happening via console logging (or some kind of markers). Is there a way to get the profiler timestamps into the console logs? Or is there a way to surface markers from my application code?

Answer (score 0):

`console.time(label)` / `console.timeEnd(label)` will create a marker in the "console" section of the profiler display.

If you're looking at particularly short events (and you mainly care about seeing when it started), it may be useful to call timeEnd from a timer after 50ms or so, otherwise the console section may not show it.